# How to remove a default action in thunar?

Tags: thunar, xfce4, thunar-custom-actions

I read the explanation to add a Custom Action, and how to remove them. But I'd like to remove the "delete" custom Action to keep only those I want.

Is it possible to Remove defaults custom actions, or to select them or do we have to keep some Custom Actions like "Delete" or others ?

[image: Thunar image]

And if yes, how can we manage ?

Comment: What do you mean by "default" custom actions? That's a bit of an oxymoron. Do you mean you want to remove some of the options (_other than custom actions_) you see when you right-click on something?

Comment: Thancks for your answer !
Sorry for my english, yes I thinck I'm talking about the options :


![Valid XHTML](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=4361129411.png).

Thanck you for your patience

Comment: Sorry, here is the link for a better pic
http://i.imgur.com/lIaizFR.png

Thanck you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand.. you want to remove the **"Delete"** action in Thunar.
Keep in mind that those are *"Default Actions"* not *"Custom Actions"*. They are in the Thunar's source code.
In order to remove the *"Delete"* default action you should download the source code, edit, and then recompile it.

**NOTE:** *In my case I'm running Xubuntu 13.04 with Thunar 1.6.2*

[image]

You can try the following:

**1)** Open a Terminal and install the necessary packages.

- `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

**2)** Install build dependencies

- `sudo apt-get build-dep thunar`

**3)** Create a folder to download the source code.

- `mkdir ~/Downloads/src`
- `cd ~/Downloads/src`

**4)** Download the source code.

- `apt-get source thunar`

**5)** Edit the the file *"thunar-standard-view.c"*

- `mousepad thunar-1.6.2/thunar/thunar-standard-view.c`

You should remove the line number "402" and save the changes.

> { "delete", GTK_STOCK_DELETE, N_ ("_Delete"), NULL, NULL, G_CALLBACK
>   (thunar_standard_view_action_delete), },

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

**6)** Go to the "thunar-1.6.2" folder to build the deb packages.

- `cd thunar-1.6.2/`
- `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b`

**7)** Now you can install the deb packages.

- `cd ..`
- `sudo dpkg -i *deb`

**8)** Finally you can logout and Login to see the changes.

**9)** Your thunar file manager should look like this: 
***(without the "Delete" Action")***

[image]

hope it helps.

Comment: WOOOOOOOOW thancks for you explanations ! they are great !

I'll try it as soon as possible, I realized, thancks to you, the important thing about having the code source !

Thancks again ! it's really great.

sharing is good - RMS -

Comment: Thanck you ! it worked great !

PS : don't forget to activate the universe packages or you'll have a little message in step 2 :)

in the ubuntu software center (logithèque ubuntu) > edit > source > and check "source code"

Thancks again !

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can remove the **Delete** context menu from settings:

- click **Edit**
- choose **Preferences**
- in tab **Behavior**, under **Context Menu**, check **Show action to permanently  delete files and folders**

But Roman Raguet's solution above works well. Gee, Thunar's context menu's getting messier like Windows Explorer :) I wish there's a simpler option to remove/arrange context menu like custom actions.