# removing the "move to dropbox" context menu option (Thunar, 16.04)

Tags: xfce, dropbox, thunar

I am really sick of the "Move to Dropbox" option in my right-click context menu. I have accidentally moved large files to Dropbox because of it many times. Is there any way to disable that option in the context menu? I am running xfce with Thunar on Ubuntu 16.04.

I have found many ways to do it on Windows and Macs, but not Linux.

- Nik.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: thunar context menu]

Comment: Which "right-click context menu"? Is it in Thunar? I installed Thunar with `--no-install-recommends` and don't see that option. I too have Dropbox installed. Could you post an image of the context menu (and some surrounding area) so it's clear?

Comment: I've added it to the post

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/337225/how-to-remove-a-default-action-in-thunar suggests you'll need to edit the source code!

Comment: Well I installed Dropbox separately from Thunar... That implies that the Dropbox package changed the source code of Thunar, recompiled it, and reinstalled it? That seems unlikely.

Comment: I have no idea. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution... it may not be the best solution, but it does work. It turns out that the dropbox context menu is a package called thunar-dropbox-plugin, which I installed to get dropbox. When I removed the package, it did remove the context menu option, but it also removed dropbox. However, on [Dropbox's install on Linux page](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux), it shows you how to install dropboxd without the package. So I looked in ~/.dropbox-dist (which apparently was not deleted when I uninstalled thunar-dropbox-plugin) and there was dropboxd. So I just added that to my autostart list and now it runs whenever I start a session.

Comment: If you want to add a sharelink context menu item, etc, this might help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/777878/how-to-integrate-dropbox-in-thunar